# Software to convert an EPS file to a vector format?

Tags: conversion, csv, eps

I've got an EPS file (provided by Ordinance Survey) which I'd like to convert into a vector file (2D points) for processing by another software application. I'm not fussed what final format it takes, as long as it's simple to understand (say, a CSV format) which can then be easily parsed. Anybody know of any free software which fits this criteria?

Comment: Then please accept your answer on how to solve it instead of editing the title.

Comment: Two day delay...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved this using Golden Software's Didger (paid for application).

Answer (score 1):

Try [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/) or [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/)

Comment: Searches through the documentation of both pieces of software implies lack of this functionality, unfortunately.

Comment: Going to have a pop at Scribus anyway.

Comment: Inkscape has a bug with importing EPS files: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/530895